# Windows 10 getting stuck on reboot, how do I find out where it's getting stuck?

Tags: windows-10, terminal-services

Windows 10 is rebooted and then hoping for Terminal Services to be available after reboot.

However after rebooting, the system appears dead (or term services at least not loading or being available) and have to force a hard reset.

What part of the EventViewer can I look at and perhaps even what event codes might tell me what's happening to the system?

Can't plug in to this system at this time. I'm just trying to diagnose the problem by looking at the logs after the hard reset.

Comment: Try enabling boot logging>>>>https://winaero.com/enable-boot-log-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Windows Logs > Application / System > in the left hand column.
Note anything in red that relates to the problem.
Please record  the event ID, and the Source Code and Google the results.

Windows Logs
https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/troubleshooting-with-windows-logs/